# Vert.x3: not able to read ClassPathXmlApplicationContext when running fatjar

Tags: java, spring, vert.x

I migrated my VertX2 application to VertX3. Everything works fine except creating a springframework bean when running the fatjar of the VertX3 application. While running within intellij everything is ok. Any idea why this happens?

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClasspathXmlApplicationContext("path to xml");
```

The xml file can be found but for some reason initializing ClassPathXmlApplicationContext  is not possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace?  Have you try with a simple context (2 beans)?

Comment: Thanks for that hint, Did not thought about the stack trace because it was catched by something (maybe vert.x itself?). ---->

is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 93; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.

but if I run it in intellij there is no problem at all, just at running it from a fatjar from the command line

Comment: I found the problem --> https://bmwieczorek.wordpress.com/2015/06/30/problems-starting-from-command-line-spring-3-and-4-applications-packaged-as-one-fat-jar-using-maven-assembly-plugin-due-to-failed-to-read-schema-document-httpwww-springframework-orgschemabean/